# How to query from a MongoDB that is a repository of CVE reports?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have to query from a mongodb collection which contains CVE reports of all softwares, as per nvd. By using the find function apparently I can query only first 20 documents, is there any other possible way by which I can query data from the database  based on the product name and vendor? The database contains about 20,000 documents  and is in a nested array form.

```
<html>
<body background="img/bluebg.jpg">

<?php

$f = $_POST["From"];
$t= $_POST["To"];

<script type="text/javascript">
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost/nvd';

var obj = require("C:\MAMP\htdocs\mapping.json");
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  for (i in obj.sector) {
       v=obj.sector[i].Vendor;

    for (j in obj.sector[i].Products) {
      p = obj.sector[i].Products[j];
      console.log(v);
      console.log(p);
      db.general.find( {
                        CVE_Items:{
                            affects:{
                              vendor:{
                                vendor_name:v,
                                  product:{
                                    product_name:p
                                          }
                                      }
                                     }
                                   }                            
                          } )







    // var cursor = db.collection('general').find();
    //
    // cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
    //
    //     console.log(doc);

    //});

  //var obj = require("C:\MAMP\htdocs\mapping.json");

</script>

?>
</br>
<p1><b>VENDOR : </b></p1>
<?php echo $v; ?></br>
<p1><b>PRODUCT : </b></p1>
<?php echo $p; ?></br></br></br></br>

<table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Published</th>
                <th>CWE</th>
                <th>CVE ID</th>
                <th>Modified</th>
                <th>Summary</th>
            </tr>
            <?php foreach ($characters as $character) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td> <?php echo $character->Published; ?> </td>
                <td> <?php echo $character->cwe; ?> </td>
                <td> <?php echo $character->id; ?> </td>
                <td> <?php echo $character->Modified; ?> </td>
                <td> <?php echo $character->summary; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the sample json file from which I am mapping each vendor to product and then fetch cve of that product.

```
{
 "sector" :[
        { "Vendor" : "Microsoft", "Products":["windows_10" , "office" , "word"]},
        { "Vendor" : "Oracle", "Products":["sql_trace_analyzer" , "project_contracts"]},
       ]
}
```

Comment: Can you post your query?

Answer (score 0):

> By using the find function apparently I can query only first 20
>   documents

This [behavior](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/) is expected,   in the mongo shell, the cursor is returned and it prints up to the first 20 documents in the results. To access more documents from a cursor iteratively, you need to use `it` in mongo shell.

> Is there any other possible way by which I can query data from the
>   database based on the product name and vendor?

Assuming the collection name cve_reports, you can query based on product name and vandor name.

```
db.cve_reports.find({product_name: 'p', vendor:'v'})
```

If executed in mongo shell, this query will return a cursor and first 20 documents will be returned, you can iterate using `it`.

You can the result of a query in a variable and iterate over it.

```
var results = db.cve_reports.find({product_name: 'p', vendor:'v'})
```